# Stop listening for actions in NGRX

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have some common components that dispatch an action. For example Status Selection, this component is used across my application in different modules, in each module I have effects being triggered by this action.

Now, if I have child modules: Module A -> Module B -> Module C, each listening to my Status Selection, if I'm in Module C, the actions of Module A are still being dispatched and I don't want that, I want each Module to be isolated even from its parents.

Is there a way to stop or destroy the listeners for actions after I'm not anymore in its Module?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. When you select any part of your store and u use the `subscribe` method this return a`subscription` you can use the method `unsubscribe` when you want.

But your store not need be designed by your components. if you have a One "Status Selection" you can have StatusSelectionAState, StatusSelectionBState, StatusSelectionCState, etc ... and subscribe - unsubscribe when you want.

Comment: Ooook I was using effects for this, but just subscribing to the Status Selection in the component for "Module C" and unsubscribe in the destructor is what I needed. Then just dispatch whatever I need in the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

An action will always be dispatched to every registered reducer and effect.
There is no built-in way to only dispatch an action to a specific reducer/module/effect.